# Optimize the code for same conditions in PHP for each variable

Tags: php, variables, optimization, foreach

Optimize the code for same conditions in PHP for each variable
can is this possible to minimize the code with using array or any other php code or commands
here is 10 check for 5nos. of inputs. i want set in one or two lines is it possible.

```
if((!is_numeric($wc)) or ($wc == 0)  or 
    (!is_numeric($tvmax)) or ($tvmax == 0) or 
    (!is_numeric($tvmin)) or ($tvmin == 0) or
    (!is_numeric($Rmsag)) or ($Rmsag == 0) or
    (!is_numeric($RGndC)) or ($RGndC == 0)) 

    {

        $unshow = "unshow"; //This variable used for hide calculated script download button;

        if((!is_numeric($wc)) or ($wc == 0)){
            $dataerr .= '<span class="emailerr"><li>Weight of Conductor value is invalid!</li></span>';
        }
        if((!is_numeric($tvmax)) or ($tvmax == 0)) {
            $dataerr .= '<span class="emailerr"><li>Tension Values at Maximum Temp. is invalid!</li></span>';
        }
        if((!is_numeric($tvmin)) or ($tvmin == 0)) {
            $dataerr .= '<span class="emailerr"><li>Tension Values at Minimum Temp. is invalid!</li></span>';
        }
        if((!is_numeric($Rmsag)) or ($Rmsag == 0)) {
            $dataerr .= '<span class="emailerr"><li>Minimum Ground Clearance with sag Error value is invalid!</li></span>';
        }
        if((!is_numeric($RGndC)) or ($RGndC == 0)) {
            $dataerr .= '<span class="emailerr"><li>Maximum Sag value is invalid!</li></span>';
        }

    } else {
        //some code, calculations, while, fopen and more codes to be execute
    }
```

Comment: Are there any problems beside "I don't know how to do it" you are encountering?

Comment: no i have no any problem with this and no any error occurred, but i want to know any other way to optimized this like this:
if(is_numeric($a, $b, $c)) like this

Comment: There are a couple ways to do optimize this sort of thing, but they are not 1 or 2 lines...

Answer (score 3):

You can optimize the code as follow:
1) create a method which will check the condition and return the error message wrapped in a span tag.
e.g.

```
validate(var, msg){
    if((!is_numeric($var)) or ($var == 0)){
        $dataerr .= '<span class="emailerr"><li>'.$msg.'</li></span>';
        }
}
```

2) then create two list containing the variables and corresponding error message.
3) Now call the method with items of list in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Readability nose-dives doing it this way, but if your goal for some reason is the least amount of lines of code you could use [Ternary operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation), there are several ways you could do it, but for example.

```
$dataerr = '';
(!is_numeric($wc) || $wc == 0) ? $dataerr .= '<span class="emailerr"><li>Weight of Conductor value is invalid!</li></span>' : null;
(!is_numeric($tvmax) || $tvmax == 0) ? $dataerr .= '<span class="emailerr"><li>Tension Values at Maximum Temp. is invalid!</li></span>' : null;
(!is_numeric($tvmin) || $tvmin == 0) ? $dataerr .= '<span class="emailerr"><li>Tension Values at Minimum Temp. is invalid!</li></span>' : null;
(!is_numeric($Rmsag) || $Rmsag == 0) ? $dataerr .= '<span class="emailerr"><li>Minimum Ground Clearance with sag Error value is invalid!</li></span>' : null;
(!is_numeric($RGndC) || $RGndC == 0) ? $dataerr .= '<span class="emailerr"><li>Maximum Sag value is invalid!</li></span>' : null;

if ($dataerr != '') {
    //some code, calculations, while, fopen and more codes to be execute
}
```

or like this,

```
(is_numeric($RGndC) && $RGndC > 1) ?: $dataerr .= '<span class="emailerr"><li>Maximum Sag value is invalid!</li></span>';
```

or you could do it like this,

```
$dataerr .= (!is_numeric($RGndC) || $RGndC == 0) ? '<span class="emailerr"><li>Weight of Conductor value is invalid!</li></span>' : '';
```

This might give you very few lines of code, but I personally find it harder to read/maintain.

Comment: Casting is not always good in, for example, form fields validation.

Answer (score 0):

One of couple of examples:

```
$aValues = array(
    'wc'    => $wc,
    'tvmax' => $tvmax,
    'tvmin' => $tvmin,
    'Rmsag' => $Rmsag,
    'RGndC' => $RGndC,
);

$aLabels = array(
    'wc'    => 'Weight of Conductor',
    'tvmax' => 'Tension Values at Maximum Temp.',
    'tvmin' => 'nsion Values at Minimum Temp.',
    'Rmsag' => 'Minimum Ground Clearance with sag Error',
    'RGndC' => 'Maximum Sag',
);

$dataerr = '';

foreach($aValues as $i => $mValue) {
    if((!is_numeric($mValue)) || ($mValue == 0)) {
        $dataerr .= '<span class="emailerr"><li>'.$aLabels[$i].' value is invalid!</li></span>';
    }
}

if(empty($dataerr)) {
    //some code, calculations, while, fopen and more codes to be execute
}
```

Comment: Not a problem ;). Upvote and check as answer, if You can, please ;).

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken all you want is to reduce the number of lines here? Populate an array of values instead of individual variables and define a constant VAR_NAMES array so you can print the appropriate name:

```
//constant array of variables names
$VAR_NAMES = array("Weight...","Tension...","Tension...","Minimum...","Maximum...");
//populate this array with corresponding values
$var_values = array(1,2,3,4,5);

for($i=0;$i<count($var_values);$i++){
    if(!is_numeric($var_values[$i]) || $var_values[$i]==0){
        $unshow = "unshow";
        $dataerr .= '<span class="emailerr"><li>$VAR_NAMES[$i] is invalid!</li></span>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow !
really awesome
if it works perfect, then you are a really gr8 man
thanks dude

Answer (score 0):

You have to many conditions to be met, so one or two lines will be hard.
You can tho, remove the first if(), and just do:

```
    if((!is_numeric($wc)) or ($wc == 0)){
        $dataerr .= '<span class="emailerr"><li>Weight of Conductor value is invalid!</li></span>';
        $unshow = "unshow";
    }
    if((!is_numeric($tvmax)) or ($tvmax == 0)) {
        $dataerr .= '<span class="emailerr"><li>Tension Values at Maximum Temp. is invalid!</li></span>';
        $unshow = "unshow";
    }
    if((!is_numeric($tvmin)) or ($tvmin == 0)) {
        $dataerr .= '<span class="emailerr"><li>Tension Values at Minimum Temp. is invalid!</li></span>';
        $unshow = "unshow";
    }
    if((!is_numeric($Rmsag)) or ($Rmsag == 0)) {
        $dataerr .= '<span class="emailerr"><li>Minimum Ground Clearance with sag Error value is invalid!</li></span>';
    }
    if((!is_numeric($RGndC)) or ($RGndC == 0)) {
        $dataerr .= '<span class="emailerr"><li>Maximum Sag value is invalid!</li></span>';
        $unshow = "unshow";
    }

    else {
        //some code, calculations, while, fopen and more codes to be execute
    }
```

This is not pretty coding, ill agree to that. But problem with this block needs to be solved before this point. Creating a function to do the job can shorten the code a little

```
public function check($variable, $message)
{
    if(!is_numeric($variable) or ($variable == 0)
    {
        $unshow = "unshow";
        return '<span class="emailerr"><li>'.$message.'</li></span>';
    }
    else return null;
}
```

Then you're code can look like this:

```
$dataerr .= check($wc, 'Wheight of Conductor value is invalid!');
$dataerr .= check($tvmax, 'Tensuon Values at Maximum Temp. is invalid!');
```

Code is not tested, but you get the point :) gl.